# Why wont my NOW() function work

Tags: mysql

Why is my NOW() function in mySQL statement, always setting the date to 01-01-1970 01:00:00 instead of the current date and time?

This is my statement.

```
("INSERT INTO transactions 
(phoneid,ip, created, cardid, pricebefordiscount, 
priceafterdiscount, discount, transactiontime, 
raw, restaurant_id, confirmed, processed, before_after_discount, 
fix, error, waiter, referer)


Values
(0,0,0,'$memberparamter','$discountPrice','$new_subtotalparamter',null,NOW(),null,'$rest_id',0,0,0,0,0,0,0)");
```

Comment: What type is the column?

Comment: The column is a varchar

Comment: date functions only work on date fields

Comment: @Rufinus not entirely true - `NOW()` can return data in a string context. (It's not a good idea to do, of course.) Zaz - how do you determine the value is set to 1970?

Comment: @Rufinus Well, it should work to insert a date value as a string, it'll just be **quite** annoying to query. That said, don't do it.

Comment: Why dont you use sysdate() instead of now()

Comment: @Pekka웃 : I am not sure i understand the question, But it is not something I determine. It is just happining.  Why? I dont know.

Comment: How do you find out it's set to 1970? What tool do you use to see the value? Maybe the error is in the script / tool you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The field transactiontime must be DATETIME and you will can use NOW() '2013-06-11 12:45:34' or CURDATE() '2013-06-11' or CURTIME() '12:45:34'.

Good luck.